# Using the isin() function on grouped data from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I would like to use something similar to the function discussed in this topic:
[Using the isin() function on grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70188603/using-the-isin-function-on-grouped-data) .
However with two DataFrames with different lengths and both grouped by variable.

The functions should group column `Dev_stage`  by year in both DataFrames, compare grouped data and provide data, which are not in one of these grouped DataFrames.

My snippet:

```
>>> df1
Out:
    Dev_stage Year
0   1         1989
1   2         1989
2   2         1989
3   3         1989
4   1         1990
5   1         1990
6   3         1990

>>> df2
Out:
    Dev_stage Year
0   1         1989
1   2         1989
2   2         1990
3   1         1990
4   3         1990
```

I was trying something like this:

```
out = lambda x, y: x[~x['Dev_stage'].isin(y['Dev_stage'])]
out(df1.groupby('Year'), df2.groupby('Year'))
```

But also get the error: `'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'isin'`. I thought that lambda will solve this one.

Expecting something like this:

```
out:   
    Dev_stage Year
3   3         1989
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use inner merge to keep the same values among multiple columns, then filter them out

```py
out = df1[~df1.index.isin(df1.reset_index().merge(df2, how='inner')['index'])]
```

```
print(out)

   Dev_stage  Year
3          3  1989
6          3  1990
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.merge` with `indicator=True`:

```
In [958]: out = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True).query('_merge != "both"').drop('_merge', 1)

In [959]: out
Out[959]: 
   Dev_stage  Year
3          3  1989
```

Comment: I don't know if this one would work because if there is a single 3 in the df2 then it throws back 0 results as opposed to 1 result. For example if there is a 3|1990 in df2 then it will have 0 results. I like this way, but it seems limited could it be more dynamic?

Comment: Why would it return 0 rows if there's a single `3` in df2? It'll return `1` row. Am I missing something in understanding your question?

Comment: Sure, I'm not sure if I could post it here through since it would need a little explanation of the data I used is there an easier way?

Comment: Trying to add coding here ```df1 = pd.DataFrame(
[[1, 1989],
[2, 1989],
[2, 1989],
[3, 1989],
[1, 1990],
[1, 1990],
[3, 1990]], columns = ['Dev_stage', 'Year'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
[[1, 1989],
[2, 1989],
[2, 1990],
[1, 1990],
[3, 1989]], columns = ['Dev_stage', 'Year'])

df1[~df1.Dev_stage.isin(df2.Dev_stage)]``` You can see I just added 3, 1989 to df2 and instead of coming back with only 3, 1990 it comes back with nothing

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn Hmm you are right. I provided the not satisfying snippet. I should put a row with a value of 3 to df2['Dev_stage'] to be more comprehensible...

Comment: @MayankPorwal Fixed the snippet to be more comprehensible... Sorry for that!

Comment: @LukášTůma I got it. Please check my updated answer. It should be much simpler now.

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn I've updated my answer. Please have a look. All cases should be covered.